# IE only CSS not applied

Tags: html, css

I have a rather odd CSS problem.

I am bringing in an Internet Explorer only CSS file with:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
```

But the file seems to of stopped updating on the server.
For example, nothing changes, even if I remove my previous header fixes and set the body background to pink (the header fix by itself should be quite clearly disabled).

I have opened the file in question in IE directly from the server location and that does reflect my most recent changes, yet an older version is being used to render the page - and yes I have cleared the catch in the browser. Really I'm quite confused why this is happening.

Comment: Remove the conditional comments and test if the CSS file affects the presentation in the other browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try temporarily renaming your css as ie1.css and fetch it in the page using href="ie1.css"

If this still does not work, something else is clearly overriding your styles from this CSS file; maybe some other stylesheet? use the IE developer toolbar to inspect where it inherits its styles from, by using the "Element source with style" thingy

Comment: Found the is trick to overcome the problem (it is recurring). Simply switch between site pages to force the CSS to refresh. Don't know why, but it works.